# Show that $G$ is differentiable on $R$ and calculate its derivative.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb R$ and define $$G(x) = \int _0 ^{\sin x}f(t)dt$$ for $x \in \mathbb R$. Show that $G$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R$ and calculate its derivative.

Attempt: 
Let $h >0$. Then, $$\frac {G(x+h) - G(x)}{h} = \frac {\int_{\sin(x)}^{\sin(x+h)}f(t) dt}{h}.$$

Let $c,t \in \mathbb R$. Then, $\forall\varepsilon, \exists\delta>0$ s.t. if $|t-c|<\delta, |f(t)-f(c)|<\varepsilon.$
This implies that $f(c) - \varepsilon < f(t) < f(c) + \varepsilon.$

Take integral on each side and divide by $h$. Then, we have $$\frac{\int_{\sin (x)}^{\sin(x+h)}(f(c)-\varepsilon) dt}{h} \le \frac{\int_{\sin (x)}^{\sin(x+h)}f(t)dt}{h} \le \frac{\int_{\sin (x)}^{\sin(x+h)}(f(c)+\varepsilon)dt}{h}.$$

This implies : $(\sin(x+h)-\sin(x))(f(c) -\varepsilon)/h \le \frac{\int_{\sin (x)}^{\sin(x+h)}f(t)dt}{h}\le (\sin(x+h)-\sin(x))(f(c) +\varepsilon)/h.$

I am stuck here. I was planning to show $|\frac{\int_{\sin (x)}^{\sin(x+h)}f(t)dt}{h}- \cdot| < \varepsilon.$ But, I don't know what to do here. Could you give some help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt$, then $G(x)=F\bigl(\sin(x)\bigr)$. Now, use the chain rule and the fundamental theorem of Calculus.

Comment: But, isnt your solution assuming the differentiability of $G$?

Comment: @SihyunKim No. I am expressing $G$ as the composition of two differentiable functions. It follows from that that $G$ is differentiable.